# each item(child list) is list showing None on .sort() function

Tags: python, sublist

```
my_list = [["abc", "def"], ["def", "abc"], ["abc", "def"]]
def list_sort_compare(org_list):
    for each_item in org_list:
        print("----" , each_item , "----")
        ei = each_item.sort()
        print(ei)
```

It is giving output like:

```
---- ['abc', 'def'] ----
None
---- ['def', 'abc'] ----
None
---- ['abc', 'def'] ----
None
```

what I am expecting is: specific to 2nd time loop where ['def', 'abc'] changed to ['abc', 'def']

```
---- ['abc', 'def'] ----
['abc', 'def']
---- ['def', 'abc'] ----
['abc', 'def']
---- ['abc', 'def'] ----
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: `sort()` changes the list itself and returns None. You may want to print `each_item` instead `ei` and remove `ei` altogether

Comment: Amazing Kuro, I was really making a silly mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is `sort()` which sorts the iterable in-place, and `sorted()` which returns the sorted result.

As @kuro said, you can return `each_item` which is already sorted, or use different function.

Answer (score 0):

Using sorted to return a sorted list and list comprehension:

```
my_list = [["abc", "def"], ["def", "abc"], ["abc", "def"]]

sortted_list = [sorted(sub_list) for sub_list in my_list]
print(sortted_list)
```

**Result:**
`[['abc', 'def'], ['abc', 'def'], ['abc', 'def']]`